# mask a password in httpd.ldap.conf file

Tags: linux, apache, active-directory

## LDAP Production configuration

#

AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
   AuthLDAPBindDN "simonid=14324,ou=applications,o=xxxxx"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword **xxxxx**

AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://xxxx.nam.nsroot.net:786/ou=internal,o=xxxxx,c=US?uid?sub?"

Hi here is my ldap.conf file. where i need to mask the password which is been exposed. what would be the best possible way to implement this. i am looking for the solution which can i implement on this . please let me know the solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

As best as I've been able to tell from [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapbindpassword), your only option (apart from writing your own Apache module for the purpose) is to write an executable file that prints the password to stdout. Within that program, you can do as much masking as you like.